# How to merge pandas dataframes from two separate lists of dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have two lists of dfs

```
List1 = [df1,df2,df3]
List2 = [df4,df5,df6]
```

I want to merge the first df from List1 with the corresponding df from List 2. ie df1 with df4 and df2 with df5, etc.

The dfs share a common column, 'Col1'. I have tried the following code

```
NewList = []
for i in len(List1),len(List2):
    NewList[i]=pd.merge(List1[i],List2[i],on='Col1')
```

I get the error 'list index out of range'.

I realise that this seems to be a common problem, however I cannot apply any of the solutions that I have found on Stack to my particular problem.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Seems like you're confused about how to write a loop over two lists in Python, and how to insert items into a new list. Your question is not a pandas question per se

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To loop over two lists and compare them or perform an operation on them element-to-element, you can use the `zip()` function.

```
import pandas as pd

List1 = [df1,df2,df3]
List2 = [df4,df5,df6]

NewList = []
for dfa, dfb in zip(List1, List2):
    # Merges df1, df4; df2, df5; df3, df6
    mdf = dfa.merge(dfb, on = 'Col1')
    NewList.append(mdf)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
pd.concat(
    [df1, df2]
)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate please?

Comment: From the way the question is structured it is not clear to me what the desired answer is. Do you want to receive one DataFrame as an output or many per row?

Other things that might be solutions for you:

pd.concat([df1, df2]).transpose()

or 

df1.merge(df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)

Comment: Here's a great link from pandas documentation which is really useful:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html

Comment: I have completely reworded the question. I provided too much information in my initial question which just caused confusion. My bad